# mysql is not working with less then and greater then value

Tags: mysql

I hav created sql query where I would like to get data that are greater then start time and less then end time means in between those time but the problem is that I am not getting any results in return can anyone help me out my time is in integer

```
$sql  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE address = '$address' AND start_time >= '$start_time' AND end_time <= '$end_time' LIMIT 1");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

Here is data of db

```
address : 1351 Powell St
start_time : 900
end time : 1080
```

My inserted query is

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
WHERE address = '1351 Powell St' AND start_time >= '915' AND end_time <= '930' LIMIT 1
```

I do not know why it is returning 0 recods

Comment: Well.. last time I checked 900 is less than 915 and 1080 is more than 930, not the other way around. Perhaps that's changed? ;P

Comment: @JonStirling well lol sorry but where this is written I am unable t find maybe I had made a mistake but if so please help me out so I can correct it

Comment: I just told you where the error is.

Comment: `900 >= 915` False , `1080 <= 930` false so true AND false AND fals = no data to fetch

Comment: @AzizShaikh I run this in sql SELECT * FROM listings WHERE address = '1351 Powell St' AND start_time >= 930 AND end_time <= 1000 LIMIT 1 and got 0 results

Comment: @MarkAlan Think about it for a second. `start_time >= 930` means that you're asking for rows where the column start_time has a value greater than or equal to 930. You say the value in your database is 900. Is 900 greater than or equal to 930? No, no it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query won't return any rows because doesn't match the criteria.

```
start_time >= '915' AND end_time <= '930'
```

Your `end_time` is 1080, greater than 930, so it won't return any value. The same with the `start_time`.

Answer (score 1):

Per your posted data condition should be other way round like

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
WHERE address = '1351 Powell St' 
AND start_time <= '915' 
AND end_time >= '930' 
LIMIT 1
```

BTW, are those `start_time` and `end_time` time column is of type `INT` or `VARCHAR`? Cause if they are string type then I wonder how the `>=` comparison is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If start_time and end_time are type of integers, then try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings 
WHERE address = '1351 Powell St' 
      AND start_time >= 915
      AND end_time <= 930
LIMIT 1;
```

Your end_time is 1080, greater than 930, so it won't return any value. Your start_time is 900, less than 915, so it won't return any value.